# How to make objects inherited from the base class access a character method but have its own result?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, visual-studio-2012

I want to be able to use my object of hero class to call the public function getAttack() from characters and generate a specific value just for that object. How can i do this? I tried using the setAttack, and it works, but when i call getAttack nothing is shown.

```
//main
int main()
{
    Characters h;//Created using normal constructor
    h.setAttack(3);
    h.getAttack();//i want this to lets say be 3
    Hero Me;
    Me.setAttack(5);
    Me.getAttack();//and this like 5 or something
    Hero::Hero(1,2,3,4);//Created using overloaded constructor
    Monsters m;
    Monsters::Monsters(5,6,7,8);

    cin.sync();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

//Hero.h
class Hero:
    public Characters
{
    public:
        Hero();
        Hero(int, int, int, int);
        ~Hero(void);
}

//Hero.cpp
int Herolevel;
int HeroHp;
int HeroStrength;
int HeroAttack;
int HeroDefense;

Hero::Hero()
{
    cout << "HOLA! Hero Created using normal constructor\n";
}

Hero::Hero(int newHp, int newLevel, int newAttack, int newDef)
{
    cout << "Hero created using Overloaded function!\n";
    HeroHp = newHp;
    cout << "Hp is: "<< HeroHp << endl;
    Herolevel = newLevel;
    cout << "level is: " << Herolevel << endl;
    HeroAttack = newAttack;
    cout << "Attack is: " << HeroAttack << endl;
    HeroDefense = newDef;
    cout << "Defense is: " << HeroDefense << endl;
}


Hero::~Hero(void)
{
     cout << "Hero destroyed!\n";
}

//Monsters.h
class Monsters:
     public Characters //Hero
{

    public:
        Monsters(void);
        Monsters(int, int, int, int);
        Monsters(int);
        ~Monsters(void);
};

//Monsters.cpp
int Monsterlevel;
int MonsterHp;
int MonsterStrength;
int MonsterAttack;
int MonsterDefense;

Monsters::Monsters(void)
{
    cout <<"Monster Created";
}

Monsters::Monsters(int newHp, int newLevel, int newAttack, int newDef)
{
    cout << "Monster created using Overloaded function!\n";
    MonsterHp = newHp;
    cout << "Hp is: "<< MonsterHp << endl;
    Monsterlevel = newLevel;
    cout << "level is: " << Monsterlevel << endl;
    MonsterAttack = newAttack;
    cout << "Attack is: " << MonsterAttack << endl;
    MonsterDefense = newDef;
    cout << "Defense is: " << MonsterDefense << endl;
}

Monsters::~Monsters(void)
{
     cout << "\nMonster Destroyed";
}

//Characters.h
class Characters
{
    private:
       int level;
       int Hp;
       int Strength;
       int Attack;
       int Defense;

    public:
       Characters(void);
       Characters(int, int, int, int);
       ~Characters(void);


     int getAttack();
     int getDefense();
     int getStrength();
     int getHp();
     int getLevel();

     void setAttack(int);
     void setDefense(int);
     void setStrength(int);
     void setHp(int);
     void setLevel(int);
};

Characters::Characters(void)
{
    cout << "\nCharacter has been created!\n";
}


Characters::~Characters(void)
{
    cout << "Character has been destroyed!\n";
}

void Characters::setHp(int damage)//get Character left over hp
{
    Hp -= damage;
}

void Characters::setAttack(int att)
{
    Attack = att;
    cout << "your attack is: " << Attack;
}

int Characters::getAttack()
{
    return Attack;
}

int Characters::getDefense()
{
    return Defense;
}

int Characters::getStrength()
{
    return Strength;
}

int Characters::getHp()
{
    return Hp;
}

int Characters::getLevel()
{
    return level;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code please.

Comment: Your code seems to be right. Did you want to display it to the screen?

Comment: Also, little tip, don't capitalize data members, it makes the code confusing to read.

Comment: @user2482488: A good coder is all about being disciplined, I think you should consider taking both the above advices :)

Comment: -1: Please properly format your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I formatted my code now :)

Comment: @Captain Skyhawk, yes i wanted to display it. When a value is returned, isn't it automatically displayed on the screen?

Comment: Those variables at the top of Hero.cpp and Monsters.cpp should probably be class members (even if you only expect one object of each class to exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your answer to my comment, here's what you're looking for:

```
int Characters::getAttack()
{
    cout << "Your attack is: " << Attack << endl;
    return Attack;
}
```

You simply forgot the cout statement that was in your setAttack method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cout in getAttack()!
The value is returned but not printed to the console.